# Can I get grep to return the true number of occurances in several files?

Tags: linux, bash, grep

Assume that you have several text files, and you want to see which text contains the word 'the' how often. The first idea seems to be to use `grep` with the `-c` option:

```
$ grep -Hciw 'the' *
```

Unfortunately, this gives the wrong count, as it counts each line with the word only once, regardless of how many instances of 'the' actually are in the line.

For a single file, I could use the option `-o` in combination with `wc` to get the occurances:

```
$ grep -owi 'the' file.txt | wc -l
```

But if I were to replace the `file.txt` with an asterisk or a file list, I would only get the accumulated number of hits, not the hits per file.

The best way I have found so far is as a loop:

```
for f in *; do
    num=$(grep -oiw 'the' $f | wc -l);
    echo ${f}:${num};
done
```

But is this really the best way?

Comment: You might make a preprocessed copy of the files with `tr ' ' '\n'` to put every word on its own line ... Probably better to use `awk` though.

Comment: All three answers from are good, and quite different. In the end, I decided to go with @Jotne, because his doesn't need a single pipe. But all three are worth understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a a way to do it with `gnu awk` (gnu due to multiple character in RS)

```
awk -v RS=" |\n" '/\<[Tt]he\>/ {a[FILENAME]++} END {for (i in a) print i,a[i]}' *
```

It will print result like this:

```
file1 22
file3 4
```

It counts the number of the word `the` and store it in an array using the name of the file as referent.

---

This should work with all `awk`

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (tolower($i)~/^the[.,?]*$/) a[FILENAME]++} END {for (i in a) print i,a[i]}' *
```

Comment: Looks good, but the 'the' seems to be case sensitive, so if 'The' is the first word of the sentence, it doesn't get counted.

Comment: @chw21 can be fixed with change `$i=="the"` to `tolower($i)=="the"` or `/\<[Tt]he\>/`

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try below command and let me know if you face any difficulties.

```
$ find . -name \*.txt | xargs -I {} sh -c 'echo {}; grep -oiw 'the' {} | wc -l'
```

By this command the output will come in below format:

```
./file-1.txt
4
./file-2.txt
4
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
grep  -Hoiw 'the' * |awk -F\: '{a[$1]++}END{for (i in a){print i":"a[i]}}'
```